# HP Spectre x360 -- How to disable trackpad automatically when going into Tablet Mode?

Tags: touchpad, tablet

The HP Spectre x360 is a "convertible" laptop, meaning it is able to bend all the way backwards to become a tablet. Whenever I do this, Ubuntu automatically disables the keyboard, which is nice. However, it fails to disable the trackpad. This can be very annoying. Is there any way I could fix this error?